# Как найти средний элемент в `std::set` с нечётным количеством элементов?

Tags: c++

Как найти средний элемент в `std::set` с нечётным количеством элементов?

Comment: Что для Вас "средний элемент" и в чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: @alexolut элемент с индексом `mySet.size()/2`

Comment: В `std::set` нет индексов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, Вам нужно что-то следующего вида:

```
std::set<какой_то_тип> s;
// ...
auto iter = s.cbegin();
std::advance(iter, s.size() / 2);
```

Здесь используется [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) чтобы переместить итератор на указанное число позиций.

Comment: Ещё бы узнать - зачем.

Comment: отлично, спасибо

Comment: @alexolut нахождение среднего элемента довольно частая задача, так константа времени работы лучше, чем при сортировке массива

Comment: @user237432 Вы используете `set` не по назначению, если у Вас возникла такая задача. `set` это множество, используется, когда нужно хранить информацию о наличии какого-либо элемента. Позиция в общем случае не важна. Если важна позиция, стоит предпочесть другой контейнер, например, `vector`.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну, такое обычно нужно для нахождения 50%-ной квантили какой-нибудь выборки данных.

Comment: @user237432, только учтите, что `std::set` использует двунаправленные итераторы. `std::advance(iter, s.size() / 2);` отработает за линейное время. Сортированный вектор в данном случае окажется быстрее

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать последовательным перебором, используя итератор класса, так как стандартный класс `std::set` не имеет итераторов произвольного доступа, а имеет двусторонние итераторы. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
    std::set<int> s = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    int middle = *std::next( s.begin(), s.size() / 2 );

    std::cout << middle << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
4
```

Comment: имхо, `std::advance()` лучше отражает намерения

Comment: @user237432 Для этого вам придется засорять пространство имен новым именем для хранения итератора, который, по существу, используется только в одном временном выражении.